# Problem in connecting server to Internet

Tags: networking, internet

I just have setup a Linux server. But currently I am having problem in connecting to the outside world. I am not able to do wget,apt-get or ping. Here ar some relevant details:

```
$ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

---

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf

search dmust.local
nameserver 198.154.126.1
```

---

```
vim /etc/network/interfaces

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 198.154.126.179
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 198.154.126.0
        broadcast 198.154.126.255
        gateway 198.154.126.1
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 198.154.126.1
        dns-search dmust.local
```

---

**Update**

```
route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
198.154.126.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         198.154.126.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
```

---

```
grep '^hosts' /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:          files dns
```

Comment: Give the output of `route -n` instead of `route` since we don't know what `localnet` is.  But it looks like the problem may be your nameserver.  Try `ping 8.8.8.8` and if that works, try `host google.com 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: In addition to what depquid said, can you also provide `grep '^hosts' /etc/nsswitch.conf`?

Comment: @depquid it works, both `ping 8.8.8.8` and `host google.com 8.8.8.8`. it shows googles IP and mail servers.

Comment: @Patrick please the nsswitch.conf has `hosts:          files dns` entry in it.

Comment: The problem is probably that your namerserver is invalid or broken.  Where did you get `198.154.126.1` from for the nameserver?

Comment: @depquid Sorry I am really not a network guy. I just installed the OS remotely through remote KVM, then I ran into this problem. `198.154.126.1` may be the 2nd server in the network. Is there anything you could suggest to solve it. How can I make nameserver valid ?

Comment: You have to get the nameserver IP address from whomever is providing the network connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the incorrect nameserver out of your configuration.

Check out https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/network-configuration.html#name-resolution for more information.

To use Google's free nameservers, edit your /etc/network/interfaces file as below.

Remove:

> dns-nameservers 198.154.126.1

Add:

> dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8

And then restart your network interface, via

> $ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

Comment: Thanks depquid and me.sedal for melping me out, it did resolved the issue .